# How to set :hover on a li(A) when hover an other li(B)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am daily an iOS developer, but i'm trying to give a help for a friend in php and jquery, since I didn't do Jquery for a lonnng time, im asking you guys a little help :)

So let's say I got this, for a unique ID

> < li class="listname" value="'.$id.'">

When I go hover this, I want to li:hover this for the same unique ID

> < li class="listpicture" value="'.$id.'>

My CSS job is done, when I go hover one, it does the job.

I began my script with something like that

```
$("li.listname").mouseover( function() {
  var id = $("li.listpicture").attr('value');

// and miss some job here
}
```

I feel a little bit noob on this, but I will feel free to help you with iOS Developement :)

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could make a new class for the hover effect and just assign it and remove it on hover. Im making the assumption that `id` is the id of the other element you want to show the hover effect on.

**css**

```
li:hover, .active {/*styles*/}
```

**JS**

```
$("li.listname").hover( function() {
  var id = $("li.listpicture").attr('value');
  $(id).addClass('active');
},function(){
    var id = $("li.listpicture").attr('value');
    $(id).removeClass('active');
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/6CwDY/1/)**